# Convert a table formatted variable into a string array

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

newbie PS user here.

I'm using Get-ADOrganizationalUnit to return child OU's that I want as a string array. IE "ou1","ou2","ou3", etc. The example I found returns the data in a table form. I have tried using export-csv, but that did not work well at all!
Here is what I am using to get the data:

```
$Items = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase 'OU=aa,OU=bb,OU=cc,OU=dd,DC=AD,DC=contoso,DC=CA' -SearchScope OneLevel | Format-Table Name -HideTableHeaders
```

this returns:

ThisOU

ThatOU

AnotherOU

etc.

But I need it structured as
"ThisOU","ThatOU","AnotherOU",Etc
The string array will be used in another script to create a drop down list of OUs.
Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Don't Format-Table (or any other Format-*) unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: Why are you trying to format the output? `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` returns _objects_, not text.

Comment: I was using the example from scconfigmgr.com, hoping to change the output to a string array. I also tried using select Name, instead Format-Table Name

Comment: What kind of output do you want? A list of just the OU names?

Comment: I'd like a string array. I have a script to run during SCCM task sequence where the front line tech would be presented with a drop down list of the available OU's for the newly imaged system to be placed in. That script requires 4 parameters, one of which is a string array of OUs.

Comment: In PowerShell a list = an array. If you want just the OU names as output, use `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter "(name=*)" -SearchBase "your search base" -SearchScope OneLevel | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName`.

Comment: That returns the full OU path, I only need the name of the OU, each OU name encased in " " and separated by a , 
"OU","OU2", etc

Comment: Well, I would say that in powershell list = one of the many possible types of lists. For instance System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: I took what Bill said, and then ran it through:

foreach ($i in $Items) {
$Location += $i + ","
}
And got the desired results. Thank you all!

Comment: " I only need the name of the OU, each OU name encased in " " and separated by a , "OU","OU2", etc " - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of piping through `Format-Table` (or `Select-Object`), use the `Foreach-Object` (`foreach`)  cmdlet to extract the name property into a string array.

```
[string[]] $items = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase 'OU=aa,OU=bb,OU=cc,OU=dd,DC=AD,DC=contoso,DC=CA' | foreach Name
```

If you then want to turn this array of strings into a single string along the lines of "name1","name2","name3", you can do:

```
$formattedNames = "`"$($items -join '","')`""
```

Comment: The second part is definitely more elegant than my foreach line. Thank you!